# Route renders wrong component, ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, react-router, router

I am trying to access the FolderDetail component once the url /folders/xy is called. Instead of getting FolderDetail component I always get the Folders component which lies in /folders... Please help.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

    function App() {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <Navigation />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
              <Route path="/folders" component={Folders} />
              <Route path="/folders/:id" component={FolderDetail} />
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Can you trying adding `exact` prop in Route component.

Comment: @YashJoshi hey this didnt help :( sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `exact` to all Routes components, this is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-feistel-zjrd8?file=/src/App.js) :

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/folders" component={Folders} />
          <Route exact path="/folders/:id" component={FolderDetail} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A switch takes the firs matched route so you need to reorder your routes like this, (also add `exact`)

```
 <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/folders/:id" component={FolderDetail} />
     <Route exact path="/folders" component={Folders} />
     <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
     <Route exact path="/" component={Home} exact />
 </Switch>
```

Always put the more specific routes first.

Comment: It's not necessary to reorder all routes, adding `exact` to all routes suffice !

Comment: @Lefi Tarik in theory that should suffice but the user has reported that it isn't working form him!

Comment: I think there is no theory vs practice its  about 0 and 1, i gave a  working example  without changing the order, and it was not meant to reorder routes using `react-router` because it will figure it out by default.